# How to use datahub to get spark transformation lineage?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have setup datahub and spark in k8s in different namespace, I can run spark with datahub configurations following this guide: https://datahubproject.io/docs/metadata-integration/java/spark-lineage/, my spark application will get data from Minio, then do some transformations including groupby, pivot, rename and a spark SQL query, then write result to cassandra database.

After spark execution finished, I can see my spark application in datahub, but there is no information for "Tasks" or "Lineage" in datahub, what should I do to get these data? There is very limited information in datahub document. Thanks!